# How to copy from node_modules just the files needed for distribution using grunt and grunt-contrib-copy

Tags: copy, dependencies, npm, gruntjs

I though I read somewhere that the "main" property of package.json could be used to copy just the files needed for "dist" or deployment. I supposed there was a grunt task for it, but I don't see anything that would help me or instruct me. I now copy everything under node_modules, but I certainly don't need to distribute library sample code, for example.

Is there a grunt task or any instructions on how to properly use grunt-contrib-copy to just copy the files from a node_module dependency hopefully from the config object's standard pkg object (a parsed package.json file)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

package.json doesn't contain enough information for you to know what to include. You would have to parse out all the `require` statements, but even then there are cases you can't detect, like a module loading resources, etc.

The right way to do this is for package authors to ignore the files that isn't needed using a [`.npmignore` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) or even better, use the [`files` property](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) in package.json to explicitly define what files should be included in the package.

Unfortunately though, most package authors are lazy and don't bother with any of this...

I would encourage you to open PRs on the modules in question with the `files` property.

Answer (score 12):

You can:

1) Use copy task to copy each relevant file to dest directory:

```
copy:
  js:
    files: [
      { 
         expand: true, 
         cwd: 'node_modules/jquery', 
         src: 'jquery.min.js', 
         dest: 'www/js' 
      },
      { 
         expand: true, 
         cwd: 'node_modules/jquery-mobile-bower/js', 
         src: 'jquery.mobile-*.min.js', 
         dest: 'www/js' 
      }
    ]
```

jquery.min.js and jquery.mobile-x.y.z.min.js will be both copied to www/js directory.

2) Use concat task to concat all files to a single dest file (usefull to generate unique javascript / stylesheets files)

```
concat:
  options:
    separator: ';'
  js:
    dest: 'www/js/lib.js'
    src: [
      'node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js',
      'node_modules/jquery-mobile-bower/js/jquery.mobile-*.min.js'
    ]
```

jquery.min.js and jquery.mobile-x.y.z.min.js will be merged into a single www/js/lib.js file, separated by a semicolon.

Comment: I think nowadays the "correct" way to do #2 is to use Browserify or Webpack instead of manually concatenating js files.